# Activating a link on rollover?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, rollover

Is it possible whit a simple script to activate a link just by a rollover without click?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<a onmouseover="window.location = this.href" href="http://google.com">test</a>
```

But use it wisely. No one will be expecting it.

May I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: this is for my search engine. after someone submitted a query (it shows the result) and on top next to the search button there is a "advanced search >>" and if you rollover it opens on the right

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea. It's very easy to rollover a link by accident, and I can't think of any site that does this. No one expects that behavior. BTW none of these examples will work with iframes unless the link is in the iframe (assuming that's what you are doing). Well, GL

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by activate you mean follow. This may well work on your  tag

```
onmouseover="window.location=event.target.href"
```

It's possible some browsers will block the attempt to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Using some unobtrusive javascript it can be achieved fairly easily.

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.onmouseover = function(){
    window.location.href = this.href;
};
```

**Simple [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8Nr4J/).**